# Infinite loop while attempting to install angular-cli using npm

Tags: npm, angular-cli

I have tried a couple times to install angular-cli on Mac globally via npm, resulting in the same infinite loop that could go on for ages:

```
EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp/9.5.0"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp"
gyp verb tmpdir == cwd automatically will remove dev files after to save disk space
```

A quick search shows that this is a known issue, but I could not see if there's an explanation to it or whether there is a reasonable workaround to mitigate it. Is there any way around this issue?

Node and npm are of the latest versions to this date (9.5.0 & 5.6.0 respectively).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this happened, it did not impact the installation as it seems, so at least it seems not to be a blocker.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , true faced the same problem in Mac ..trying to resolve the same. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli#prerequisites
cheers
raky

Comment: I do have all the prerequisites checked as required, but I did get the error anyway. Angular-cli seems to have been installed fine nonetheless, at least I'm using the command line to generate/build/run apps without any errors until now.